# How to get specific values from object list inside Observable to template in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I encountered this problem. I have an interface that has two fields used for search

```
export interface searchClass { 
    text: string; 
    id: number;
}
```

I use this interface in my component that is defined like this

```
searchClass$: Observable<searchClass[]> = new Observable();
```

and it has values from api binded to it.

```
this.searchClass$ = this.getSearchClass();
```

My problem that in html template I want display only text and bind only one field value array, but then when component activates I want to have ids of these text fields. How to achieve this?

I tried to do something like this,

```
<div *ngIf="(searchClass$ | async)?.text as myValues">
    <myComponent 
        [values] = myValues>
        (output) = setIds($event)>
    </myComponent>
</div>
```

but it did not work out, because `[values]` was never assigned. I came up by just creating 2 Observables, one for both fields, and one only for text, like this

```
this.getSearchClass().subscribe(data => {
    this.searchClass$ = new Observable((subscriber) => {
    subscriber.next(data);
    subscriber.complete();
  });
  const names = data.map(element => element.text);
  this.searchText$ = new Observable<string[]>(subscriber => {
    subscriber.next(names);
    subscriber.complete();
  });
```

then just have html template like this

```
<div>
    <myComponent 
       [values] = "searchText$ | async"
       (output) = setIds($event)>
   </myComponent>
</div>
```

And manage output array like this to assign selected text ids

```
setIds(text: string[]) {
   this.searchClass$.subscribe(search => {
       someOtherField = search
           .filter(element => text.includes(element.text))
           .map(element => element.id);
```

But I think it's not efficent and there's should be a way to do this without creating 2 Observables.

Comment: There are very many syntax errors in your code, for example `<div *ngIf="(searchClass$ | async)?.text as myValues">` would not compile... Please provide code that actually compiles to showcase your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div *ngIf="searchClass$ | async as myValues">
    <myComponent 
        [values] = myValues>
        (output) = setIds($event)>
    </myComponent>
</div>

setIds(myValueSelected: searchClass) {
   this.someOtherField = myValueSelected.id;
}
```

And, in your component "myComponent", you should have an input variable to get "myValues" and some to *emit" the selected value, and the logic of the selection, something like:

```
@Input()
  values!: searchClass;

@Output() output: EventEmitter<searchClass> = new EventEmitter();

// Some treatment in your myComponent
// When you get the select searchClass, you have to emit it. 
// For instance (just as an example if you finally selected the first Class of values):
const mySelectSearchClass = values[0];

this.output.emit(mySelectSearchClass);
```

Comment: Problem is that I can't modify "myComponent"